# jQuery: Finding the number of checked children in a parent of the clicked object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say you have a list like:

```
<ol>
    <li>Some text<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /></li>
    <li>Some text<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /></li>
</ol>
```

I need to see how many checkboxes in a list item are checked and do something only when both are checked.

```
$(document).ready(function(
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().children("input:checkbox") == checked) {
                do something;
            }
});
});
```

So far I have found way to get the number checked in the entire document and I can get it to tell me if "this" is checked. I appreciate any help anyone can offer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().children("input:checked").length==2) {
            do something only if 2 are selected;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :checked

```
$(document).ready(function(
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().children("input:checked").length == 2) {
            do something;
        }
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector to get the checked elements. Than you can just read the length of the result.

```
var cnt = $(this).parent().children("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

If you want to know if the current element was checked it would be as simple as

```
if (this.checked) {

}
```